# How can a StringBuilder best be converted to a String[]?

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

The following code sort of works, but fixes the number of elements in String[]. Is there a way to make a String[] add the number of elements needed dynamically?

```
private static StringBuilder names = new StringBuilder();
...
public String[] getNames() {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int i = 0;
    String[] nameArray = {"","","",""};

    while (-1 != end) {
        end = names.indexOf(TAB, start);            
        nameArray[i++] = names.substring(start, end);
        start = ++end; // The next name is after the TAB
    }
    return nameArray;
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd explain *how* you want the text to be broken up. I've made assumptions based on the code, but a description would have been nice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So you're just trying to split on tab? How about:

```
return names.toString().split(TAB);
```

Note that `split` takes a regular expression pattern - so don't expect `split(".")` to split just on dots, for example :)

Comment: My answer is doomed! Great @JonSkeet answered three seconds before I did. :-)
Read your book Jon. It's awesome.

Comment: Perfect! Only needed this one line. And yes, TAB is \t. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4):

To dynamically grow array, use `ArrayList<String>`, you can even convert the result to `String[]` if that's what your API requires.

```
ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>( );

while (-1 != end) {
    end = names.indexOf(TAB, start);            
    namesList.add( names.substring(start, end) );
    start = ++end; // The next name is after the TAB
}

return namesList.toArray( new String[ namesList.size( ) ] );
```

That said, for your purposes use `split` as suggested by others

Answer (score 2):

You can use String's method [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to do that in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive implementation to use the program stack as a temporary array.

```
public String[] getNames()
{
    return getNamesRecursively( names, 0, TAB, 0 );
}

private static String[] getNamesRecursively( StringBuilder str, int pos, String delimiter, int cnt )
{
    int end = str.indexOf( delimiter, pos );
    String[] res;
    if( end >= 0 )
        res = getNamesRecursively( str, end + delimiter.length(), delimiter, cnt + 1 );
    else
    {
        res = new String[ cnt + 1 ];
        end = str.length();
    }
    res[ cnt ] = str.substring( pos, end );
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Impractical.  If the input StringBuilder is big enough, you'll overflow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

String myLocation = builder.toString();

Answer (score -4):

```
StringBuilder t= new StringBuilder();

String s= t.toString();
```