# String Builder to String Array in java

Tags: java, arrays, stringbuilder

I am trying to convert String builder to String array in java.I have used ***to String*** method to convert the Stringbuilder to String and then use ***split*** method to convert it to String array.

I am facing some issue in array size. The output of String builder is as follows: `0,,1,,,,,,,,,,2,,,`. Actually it contains 15 elements, but it's showing the size of stringbuilder as 18. And after converting to String array, it's showing size as 13.

Am I doing wrong method? Is there is other method to convert String builder to String Array?

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (String str : listToSearch) {
    int index = findIndex(headerArrayList, str);
    if (index > -1) {
        output.append(index);
    } else {
        output.append(str);
    }
    output.append(",");
}

String out = output.toString();
String[] destIndexArray = out.split(",");
```

The `findIndex` method:

```
private static int findIndex(List<String> headerList, String element) {
    for (int i = 0; i < headerList.size(); i++) {
        if (headerList.get(i).equals(element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: How about using a list instead of the stringbuilder??

Comment: you should use a list, instead of String builder. At last just convert it into Array

Comment: Also check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Comment: But it contains both integer values and String values.

Comment: see finally, you are getting an array of String. So in list just save integer as String.

Answer (score 5):

> Am I doing wrong method?

There are many places your code need improvements. I'm suggesting some:

1. Instead of re-inventing wheel, look for existing API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

---

2. You can add only `String`s instead of index.

---

```
for (String str :listToSearch) {
    int index=headerArrayList.indexOf(str);
    if (index < 0) {
        output.append(str);
        output.append(",");
    }
    // if(!headerArrayList.contains(str))
    // output.append(str);
    // output.append(",");
}
```

---

3. Use `List<String>` instead of `StringBuilder`.

> Is there is other method to convert String builder to String Array?

Yes, but if you follow above points, you won't need it. but since you asked. See this: [How can a StringBuilder best be converted to a String[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472234/how-can-a-stringbuilder-best-be-converted-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

See using stringbuilder and again manipulating it and converting it into array is not a good idea. Instead insert everything into list of string, and to check if string is integer or not use this :

```
str.matches("^-?\\d+$");
```

And if you want to convert it into array you can do that

```
String[] str = list.toArray(new String[list.size()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you simply tried in it with one line code:

`stringBuilder.toString().split("delimiter");` ?

Which is in your case, might look like:

```
destIndexArray = output.toString().split(",");
```

If that doesnt work, then instead of converting into a StringBuilder, you can do this:

```
List<String> output = new List<String>();

for (String str : listToSearch) {
int index = findIndex(headerArrayList, str);
if (index > -1) {
    output.add(index);
} else {
    output.add(str);
}
}
```

I think in this case you can do whatever with your list, no need of delimiter. Hope it helps!